# grabbing visible div appending image

Tags: jquery

I am stuck on why this will not work out.
Grabbing the visible `div` with a class of `.open` and then grabbing the `div` with the class of `.edititable` and appending an image to it.

Please any help would be great.

Here is my code:

```
$('#imagefiles ul li img').click(function() {
    //Get the source of the image that was clicked
    var img = $(this).attr('src');
    //grab the visible div and the div with class edititable within it and append image
    $(".open:visible.edititable").append('<img src="' + img + '" style="width:30%; height:30%;" ">');
});
```

Comment: What is `:visible`? I don't believe that is a valid selector.

Comment: @Leeish - its a jQuery selector

Comment: I just Googled it and I see. Interesting. Should be then: `.open.edititable:visible` I bet.

Comment: grabs all elements that are visible, so in my case it will grab all divs with the classname of .open that are visible.

Comment: It should be `$(".open:visible .edititable")`, with a space, if .edititable is inside the visible div.

Comment: Yeah, you need to clarify you HTML structure. Post your HTML and tell us which div needs the image injected into it.

Comment: Is it as simple as a typo in your class name?  Or is "edititable" vs "editable" intentional?

Comment: i want the div with the class of edititable from only the visible div with the class of .open.

Comment: Also there is what @uptownnickbrown said. See my answer for your options. And learn to spell :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `.open.edititable:visible` is probably more correct. I don't think you can do a class after the pseudo selector.

Although I am confused by:

```
//grab the visible div and the div with class edititable within it and append image
```

Do you want a `.open:visible` and a `.edititable` div (2 divs) or do you want a div with both the class `.open` and `.edititable` that is also `visible`? Or do you want the child div with the class `.editable` that is located in the div with the class `.open` that is also `visible`.

`.open.edititable:visible` Will grab a visible div with both classes `open` and `edititable`.
`.open:visible .edititable` will grab the div with the class `edititable` that is a child of the visible div with the class `open`.

Comment: I figured it out with the help of you guys. i did       $(".open:visible").find('.edititable').append('<img src="' + img + '" style="width:30%; height:30%;" ">');